# Múltiples enlaces simbólicos

Tags: linux

Hoy busco su ayuda para solucionar un problema que tengo con los enlaces simbólicos de *Python*.

El tema es este, instalé *kubuntu 18.04*, como saben ya viene con ciertas versiones de *Python*.

Mi problema radica en que metiendo mano y cambiando a donde apunta *python* creé enlaces y ahora no puedo hacer ciertas instalaciones porque algo pasa cuando hago `python3 --version` NO OK -> Demasiados niveles de enlaces simbólicos, cuando hago `python --version` está OK, me dice -> *Python 3.8.7*.

Lo que necesito es que *python3* este apuntando al 3.8.7 y *python* apunte a lo que sea mientras no sea el 3.8.7.

Soy nuevo en el SO por lo tanto no me manejo con los comandos, solo he utilizado los de `update-alternatives <ruta> <nombre>` que he encontrado en internet pero no entiendo de donde sacarlas ni nada.

Por favor alguien que pueda ayudarme a solucionar esto sin romper mi SO (he formateado 3 veces y ahora estoy atrasado con el trabajo).

---

**Respondiendo a @abulafia**

Salida de: which python

```
/usr/bin/python
```

which python3

```
No arrojo nada
```

ls -ld `which python`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 feb  1 20:46 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python3
```

ls -ld `which python3`

```
drwxr-xr-x 27 humberto humberto 4096 feb  2 13:01 .
```

ls -l /etc/alternatives

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ls -l /usr/bin/p*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A la vista de la información que has suministrado en la pregunta (a petición mía en varios comentarios que después fueron borrados para "eliminar ruido"), podemos llegar a las siguientes conclusiones:

- Cuando pones `python` sin más en la línea de comandos, lo que se intentará ejecutar es `/usr/bin/python` (esto nos lo dice `which python`)
- Pero `/usr/bin/python` en realidad no es el ejecutable, sino sólo una referencia (enlace simbólico a otro fichero). En concreto a `/etc/alternatives/python3` (esto nos lo dice uno de los `ls -ld`)
- Por su parte `/etc/alternatives/python3` es otro enlace simbólico, que apunta a `/usr/bin/python3.8`
- Y `/usr/bin/python3.8` **este sí** es un ejecutable. Lo deduzco por su tamaño (5134032 como se ve en la última imagen).

Por tanto ante el comando `python` quien termina por ser ejecutado  es `/usr/bin/pyton3.8`.

Veamos ahora qué pasa ante el comando `python3`.

- Para empezar el comando `which python3` falla y no devuelve nada. Sospecho que se debe a que el intento de ejecución terminó en un bucle de redirecciones infinito, por lo que la información de qué comando era no quedó guardada.
- Haré la hipótesis de que el comando que se intentó ejecutar era `/usr/bin/python3` (al igual que en el caso anterior vimos que al poner `python` se comenzaba por intentar `/usr/bin/python`). Además tiene sentido porque la ruta `/usr/bin` es una de las primeras donde se buscan los comandos ejecutables.
- Si miramos (segunda captura de pantalla) qué hay en `/usr/bin/python3` vemos que es un enlace simbólico que apunta a `/etc/alternatives/python3`. Vemos que además sale en rojo en ese listado, lo cual ya nos alerta que algo anda mal.
- Si miramos `/etc/alternatives` vemos que `python3` es un enlaces simbólico ¡que apunta a `/usr/bin/python3`! Es decir, un enlace apunta a otro, pero el segundo de nuevo apunta al primero. Python se ha convertido en un [Uróboro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ur%C3%B3boros) :-)

No es de extrañar que produzca el error que has visto. Si el operativo sigue los enlaces simbólicos no terminará nunca pues solo le llevan de uno a otro sin llegar nunca al fichero ejecutable final. Al cabo de unas cuantas iteraciones el operativo se cansa y te dice que "demasiados enlaces simbólicos".

### Como arreglarlo

Ahora que sabemos esto, ¿cómo arreglarlo? Habría que hacer que `/usr/bin/python` apunte a `/etc/alternatives/python` y que éste a su vez apunte a `/usr/bin/python2`  (el cual a su vez apunta a `/usr/bin/python2.7`) Con eso se lograría que al poner `python` el ejecutable final sea el de la versión 2.7.

Para lograr esto usaremos el comando `ln -s` que permite crear enlaces simbólicos (previamente habrá que borrar los enlaces que estaban mal). Esto solo puede hacerlo el administrador, por lo que tendrás que poner `sudo` delante de los comandos. Serían estos:

```
rm /etc/alternatives/python
ln -s /usr/bin/python2 /etc/alternatives/python
rm /usr/bin/python
ln -s /etc/alternatives/python /usr/bin/python
```

De forma similar borramos los enlaces simbólicos que impedían la correcta ejecución de python3 y ponemos los buenos:

```
rm /etc/alternatives/python3
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.8 /etc/alternatives/python3
rm /usr/bin/python3
ln -s /etc/alternatives/python3 /usr/bin/python3
```

Con esto al poner `python3` se ejecutará finalmente la versión 3.8 (ya que a esa es a la que apunta el enlace que había en `/etc/alternatives/python3`)

Comment: oh dios, eres un genio. Igual por mi poca experiencia se me hace un poco seguirte el hilo pero a grandes rasgos lo tengo en la mente. Ahora intentaré hacer lo que me mencionaste y te comento. Antes de todo, independiente que lo haga bien o mal solo quiero decirte que MUCHISIMAS gracias por tu tiempo, buena onda y dedicación

Comment: @Programmer89 Creo que me perdí en el laberinto de enlaces simbólicos XD. Acabo de editar de nuevo la respuesta cambiando la parte final, para arreglar el desaguisado. Si tras esto ya te funciona, creo que podrías eliminar la última edición realizada en la pregunta, para no confundir a futuros lectores.

Comment: Listoco, funcionó y está todo perfecto. Edité como me comentaste y limpie los comentarios. No me queda nada mas que decirte denuevo muchísimas gracias, exito en todo y te deseo lo mejor jajaja

Comment: Te podría molestar con una cosilla más porfa?
 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`
Esto tiene que ver con las versiones de python?

Comment: @Programmer89 Es probable que con todo el tinglado que se hizo previamente se haya roto alguna cosa. Prueba a poner otra vez bien la alternativa python3 usando `update-alternatives  --set python3  /usr/bin/python3.8` Es posible que eso además de cambiar enlaces simbólicos haga otras cosas (que nosotros no hicimos al cambiar los enlaces simbólicos "a mano"). Dime si te funcionó

Comment: Si no, también puedes probar a reinstalar ese modulo que te falta, con `apt-get install python-apt`

Comment: Solucionado master!. Encontre la solucion de 4 pasos
`sudo apt remove python3-apt`
`sudo apt autoremove`
`sudo apt autoclean`
`sudo apt install python3-apt`

No rompio nada y funcionó, asi q todo bien!